# How to express a list within a sentence?

Tags: punctuation, lists

I always forget how to express a list within a sentence. Let's say I have the following sentence:

> I attached two files, files and database.

Can I use a "-" or a ";" instead of the comma?

Please advise me.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A colon `:` is a good way to introduce a list.

```
I have attached two files: files and database.
```